# Vue.js cannot find images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

I use Vue-CLI. Vue last version (3.9.3). Vue cannot find my images.
I attached some screenshots.
Why images are not displayed?

1. First image (Structure)
2. Second image (template)
3. Third image (script)
4. Fourth image (result)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't add images. Add the code.

Comment: You should use /images/flag-1.png, if there not modified other vue cli configurations.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the following steps:

1. You need to import images in the component like this:

`import userimage from "@/assets/images/user-1.png";`

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR4xH.png)

2. Set a reference with a local variable:

`userimage: userimage,
 botimage: botimage,`

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h4d4.png)

3. Use them in HTML like:

`<img :src="userimage" alt="image">
<img :src="botimage" alt="image">`

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWxHS.png)

So basically you are importing them and using them in the template, it's that easy.

Answer (score 1):

For `src` attribute in `img` tag you can use `require("@/assets/logo.jpg")` like this:

```
<img :src="require('@/assets/logo.png')">
```